# Changing legend label for a plot

Tags: jenkins

I want to change a "Data series legend label" for a plot, say from "foo" to "bar". Is there any way to change the previously recorded values of "foo" to be values of "bar" as well?

Currently I get values of "foo" for old builds and values of "bar" for new builds if I make the change.

I assume I can manually edit the csv file, where these values are stored, but I do not have write access to those files in the setup I am using now. Even if I did, I wouldn't want to edit the csv file by hand for something which feels like it is a common requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know of to do that is to edit the file that stores the plot values.  This will be located in $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/jobname on the machine that runs your Jenkins master, and will be a .csv file with a numeric name, e.g. 280055090.csv

Comment: wow, I was simultaneously editing the question, hoping nobody saw it yet :)
thanks for the response, but please see the edit.